# Use Jquery to replace all characters after nth character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that has a variable amount of text in it. The div has a set height and if the text exceeds that height I want to create a 'Read More' link.

I am able to count the length of the text witing the div, eg:

```
$(".longdesc").each(function() {
    var count = $(this).text().length
    console.log(count); 

    if(count > 100){
      //Replace additional characters with " ...Read More"
    };

});
```

But I am unsure of how to replace all the characters after the 100th character with " ...Read More".

Would anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(count > 100){
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 100) + " ...Read More");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (count > 100) {
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 100) + ' ...Read More');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".longdesc").text(function(idx, text) {
    return text.length > 100 ? text.substring(0, 100) + '...Read More' : text;
});
```

if you want a link

```
$(".longdesc").html(function(idx, html) {
    return html.length > 100 ? html.substring(0, 100) + '<a href="#">...Read More</a>' : html;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update the the HTML of the whole `div` like so:

```
if (count > 100){
    var newText = $(this).text().substring(0,100);
    newText += "<a href='#'>Read More</a>";
    $(this).html(newText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slice:

```
text = text.slice(0, 100) + (text.slice(100)? "... Read More" : "");
```